# UnityPlayer Native Crash

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am opening and closing activities containing a Unity Player view and eventually after opening and closing multiple times the app will crash with a native error:

```
/CRASH: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) etc.
```

When I convert the symbols I get this:

```
jni::Java_bitter_jnibridge_JNIBridge_00024InterfaceProxy_delete(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long)
```

That line appears to be in here: https://github.com/bitter/android-jni-bridge/blob/master/Proxy.cpp so it is causing an error when a pointer is being deleted. I assume I haven't unloaded Unity correctly and that's the problem? Any help on how to properly unload Unity?? (I am currently using Application.Unload())

Does anyone know what this means?

p.s (I have a setup using some tutorials e.g https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-unity-android-in-a-sub-view.98315/ and https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a) so as all my code is too much to post, I'll just say I have an activity which initialises the UnityPlayer and then all of the necessary callbacks copied from UnityPlayerActivity there :))